# How I can customize antd tab active bottom tab bar color

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to change bottom tab bar color same as tab heading. I have tried several methods but unable to succeed.

**My Code:**

```
export default function OurPhilosophy() {

 return (
     <Container maxWidth="lg" className="our-philosophy">
         <h3 className="heading1">Our Philosophy</h3>

         <Demo />
     </Container>
 )
} 

const Demo = () => (
 <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" size="large">
     <TabPane tab="Heading 1" key="1">
         "Content"
     </TabPane>
     <TabPane tab="Heading 2" key="2">
         "Content"
     </TabPane>
     <TabPane tab="Heading 3" key="3">
         "Content"
     </TabPane>
     <TabPane tab="Heading 4" key="4">
         "Content"
     </TabPane>
 </Tabs>
);
```

**Screen:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3sOR.png)

Answer (score 9):

**Issue has been resolved**

here is the css

```
.ant-tabs-ink-bar {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FF5230;
}
```